# How to get the number of pixels vertically and horizontally?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I want to show a Dialog with the method signature `show(int top, int bottom, int left, int right, boolean includeTitle)`

I want to place this Dialog in the center of the screen. So I want to know the total number of pixels of the screen vertically and the total number of pixels of the screen horizontally.

How to achieve that ?

Comment: What is the need of pixels for whole screen? Once you give all four parameters same - top, bottom, left, right; it will display your dialog in center. eg. `dialog.show(20, 20, 20, 20, true);` Or if you want rectangle dialog box in center, you can call it like `dialog.show(10, 10, 20, 20, true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the methods that give you these dimensions in LWUIT then
you obtain a reference to the Display `Display.getInstance()`
then you can call getDisplayHeight() or getDisplayWidth();
but if you want to use MIDP classes you have to get a reference to the Display
by calling `Display.getDisplay(Midlet instance)` and then getting a reference to the
current Displayable `getCurrent()` and then you can call `getWidth()` or `getHeight()`.